# React - How to update a prop from a function

Tags: reactjs

I would like to pass the planet.id from the planetCard to the PlanetPanelCard when I click on the planet Card.

[Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Cgl.png)

Thank You!

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not image.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `useState` hook for that

```
[selectedPlanetId, setSelectedPlanetId] = useState(null)
```

then in Planet card pass the function

```
onClick={() => { setSelectedPlanetId(planet.id) }}
```

and in the PlanetPanelCard

```
planetId={selectedPlanetId}
```